# Disable close symbol in android free multi window screen

Tags: android, android-source, android-7.1-nougat, multi-window

Can we disable close symbol( cross symbol) in Android(7.1) free multi-window screen in android AOSP?
Please find attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Why exactly you want to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: for advertisement in public places.

Comment: As per Android Standards, You can't stop user interaction and flexibility

Comment: Ok,thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution...!! ,
We can able to disable close icon to changed the code in Android source code framework level....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It's more part of the Android system than it is part of your app.